# Issue storing value in a variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I guess this will be an easy question.
I am trying to store some data in a variable, piece of code is as follows:

```
    var g6 = document.getElementById('logo');
var g7 = g6.offsetHeight;
//...uninteresting code...
function(MyFunction){
g6.style.transform = 'scale3d(1,'+g7/g6.offsetHeight+',1)';
}
```

g6 and g7 are global variables (at least i guess i understand that).So, idea is to get div#logo height, and, as somewhen in time it shrinks, restore it to normal size by scaling.
Idea is not to use pixels, to aim for responsiveness.
The problem I am getting is that when i call for g7, instead of being a fixed number, it fluctuates along with g6.offsetHeight, so the quotient is always 1. 
Thanks in advance, as I realize it may be a silly question, a simple finger pointing in the right direction would be really appreciated.. :)
So, after reading a while I see it may be that i'm storing an object and not a value.. If so, any way to store the value and not the object?
Thanks again!

EDIT: They are NOT global variables.. They are defined inside the function. sorry about that. But anyway i can't see why the value stored change..

Comment: `offsetHeight` is a number value. `g7` will not change unless you store a new value in it. If `g7` is changing, you must be setting its value somewhere.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sure.. sorry for the delay: here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/Sourcerer/tkpa9Lfu/3/ Thanks!